# What should be targetNamespace in API that is being versioned?

Tags: xml, api, soap, xsd

Our team is developing an API which is being versioned. We have following naming schema:

```
http://example.com/remote/soap/vX.Y/wsdl
```

where `X.Y` is version number. My question is: should **targetNamespace** contain whole WSDL address or just i.e. `http://example.com/remote/soap` part?

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the Inernet, I have found following [tutorial](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx) where one can read:

> The value of targetNamespace is just a unique identifier, typically companies use there url followed by something to qualify it. **In principle the namespace has no meaning**, but some companies have used the url where the schema is stored, as the targetNamespace and so some XML parsers will use this as a hint path for the schema [...]

Taking under consideration fact that our API can significantly change among different versions, I think it would be better to provide the version number in targetNamespace URI.